# Internet Explorer Ajax Bug with Mojarra 2.1.28 and RichFaces 4.3

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, jsf, richfaces

I am working on a web application development which uses RichFaces. Currently 4.3.7 version is used.

When I have upgraded from Mojarra 2.1.27 to 2.1.28 a strange behavior introduced using Internet Explorer 8. Some of my ajax button stopped working. I did step by step analysis moving a simple ajax button in different place in the template. Finally I have realized that the problem depends on where the button is located. Outside of a form it worked. Inside in the first form worked. But inside in a second form not. The forms were not included in each other of course.

Summarizing the situation the problem exists in a very simple xhtml like this:

```
<a4j:log />
<h:form>
   <a4j:commandButton value="Hello" oncomplete="alert('Hello')" />
</h:form>
<h:form>
   <a4j:commandButton value="Hello" oncomplete="alert('Hello')" />
</h:form>
```

The first button works as expected but the second one do nothing the following warning appears in the ajax log panel (and the button do nothing):

```
richfaces.queue ajax submit error 'name' is null or object not defined
```

If I have moved the ajax button outside the form also worked. I have tried with Chrome browser and also worked as expected.

When I have changed back into jsf-api-2.1.27 and jsf-impl-2.1.27 everything worked perfect. But the RichFaces update log said that they changed to jsf 2.1.28 so I have to explorer a solution for this bug because I want to work with RF 4.3.7 and jsf 2.1.28 together.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the good solution for this problem using internet research :-)

The problem was the changes in jsf.js script of jsf-impl-2.1.28 compared to jsf.js in jsf-impl-2.1.27 was it before.

I have followed the suggested patch found here:
https://github.com/jboss/mojarra/commit/6830d0a647d8b6919440a875a5f7ec3840dabf84

I have used 7-zip to open jsf-impl-2.1.28 and have extracted the jsf-uncomressed.js file.
I have modified the script as it was suggested and minified the result into jsf.js online at http://jscompress.com/

and finally put both file back into the jar overwriting the original one using 7-zip utils

and looks miracle everything works perfect now

I hope it could help to others walking in the same shoes :-)